# HTML form - required fields - knowing if a required field has been completed programatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that loads a loading gif when a button is clicked. It works fine if required text has been entered.

If the required text has not been entered the browser indicates that the text is missing but the loading gif still kicks in.

Is there a way of js knowing that a required field has not be completed so that I can stop the loading gif from displaying?

Stripped down I have:

An HTML form that looks like this:

```
<form action="...">
    <input type="text" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

and I some js that looks like this:

```
$("button").click (function(){          
    // Display a loading gif;
});
```

What I want is something like this:

```
$("button").click (function(){
    if (all required fields are complete) {
        // Display a loading gif;
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a filter on the fields like this:

```
 $('input').filter('[required]')
```

```js
function checkInputs() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('input').filter('[required]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      $('#confirm').prop('disabled', true)
      isValid = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if(isValid) {$('#confirm').prop('disabled', false)}
  return isValid;
}

$('#confirm').click(function() {
  alert(checkInputs());
});

//Enable or disable button based on if inputs are filled or not
$('input').filter('[required]').on('keyup',function() {
checkInputs()
})

checkInputs()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input required>
  <input required>
  <input required>
  <button id="confirm">check</button>
</form>
```

Credit goes to: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42347467/4084160)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not work if there are other buttons withing another <form> on the page that do not rely on fields to be selected. The page has a number of <form action=""> on it and your code looks at all fields on the page, not just the ones  within the form where the button was clicked. I have sorted it by using js to check the name of the button clicked.